# Javascript - Loop through object with array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying out a simple BlackJack game with JS. Here are some of my codes:

```
 function card(suit, face) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.face = face;

    switch (face) {
        case "A":
            this.faceValue = 11;
            break;
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "K":
            this.faceValue = 10;
            break;
        default:
            this.faceValue = parseInt(face);
            break;
    }
};

const player = {
    cards: [],
    handValue: 0
}

const dealOneCardToPlayer = () => {     
    tempCard = deck.cards.splice(0, 1);
    player.cards.push(tempCard);
    player.handValue = countHandValue(player.cards);
}
```

I am stuck with countHandValue method which I couldn't get the faceValue of Cards for player object. I try with several types of for loop but with no success still. Once I can get the faceValue, then I can sum it up and assign to handValue property.

```
const countHandValue = (cardsOnHand) => {    
    for (const key of cardsOnHand) {
        console.log(key.faceValue);
    }

    for (const key in cardsOnHand) {
        console.log(key.faceValue);
    }
}
```

[Code Edited]I searched and found this code which i can retrieve my faceValue property but I believe there are much extra code:

```
    const countHandValue = (cardsOnHand) => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (var key in cardsOnHand) {
        var arr = cardsOnHand[key];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var obj = arr[i];
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (prop === "faceValue") {
                    console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
                    sum = sum + obj[prop];                        
                }                    
            }
        }
    }        
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you add an example where you actually deal the cards to the player for further information?

Comment: Have you tried Array.forEach()?

Comment: ya i tried with forEach but doesn't work.

Comment: @Steve, are you getting an error? What is the result when you try to print out the property values?

Comment: @francovici it is from a button at the moment

Comment: @dpberry178 it is undefined

Comment: when i debug it from the browser, i can see the whole object value: 0: Array(1)
0: card {suit: "Hearts", face: "K", faceValue: 10}
length: 1

Comment: More code would be helpful so we can see how the cards are being dealt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do consider that `A` can score as 1 *or* 11. This program shows you how to handle that -

```js
const add = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x + y

const sum = (a = []) =>
  a .reduce (add, 0)

const scoreCard = (face = "") =>
  face === "A"
    ? [ 11, 1 ]
: (face === "K") || (face === "Q") || (face === "J")
    ? [ 10 ]
: [ Number (face) ]

const allScores = ([ face = "", ...more ]) =>
  face === ""
    ? [ scoreCard (face) ]
    : allScores (more)
        .flatMap
          ( hand =>
              scoreCard (face) .map (v => [ v, ...hand ])
          )

const scoreHand = (...hand) =>
{ const [ best = "Bust" ] =
    allScores (hand)
      .map (sum)
      .filter (score => score <= 21)
  
  if (best === 21)
    return "Blackjack!"
  else
    return String (best)
}

console .log
  ( scoreHand ("A", "K")                     // Blackjack!
  , scoreHand ("A", "A", "K")                // 12
  , scoreHand ("A", "A", "K", "7")           // 19
  , scoreHand ("J", "4", "K")                // Bust
  , scoreHand ("A", "A", "A", "A", "K", "7") // Blackjack!
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cool codes. But at the moment, I stick with my code structure first for this version. So, I used that way which I have edited from my original post to get my hand value. Kinda much extra code but for the next version, I will consider to use your version.

Comment: Blackjack scoring is a non-trivial when you consider each A _doubles_ the solution space. I made these independent functions so you can see a clear separation of concerns and adapt them to your program as needed. As long as your program outputs the correct score for _every_ hand, you're good :D

Comment: I added a final test to show that "AAAAK7" scores properly

Comment: @Steve I saw in a comment you're looking for `reduce`. I just wanted to let you know that [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is a specialized form of `reduce` and it's the core of this answer

Comment: i will look into this flatMap. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `reduce`:

```
const coundHandValue = cards => cards.reduce((acc, { faceValue }) => acc + faceValue, 0);
```

Comment: Nice. I am looking for reduce. But faceValue is still undefined.